# Office365 Allow Spoofing Emails for 3rd Party Client

Tags: email, office365, exchange-server, spf, dkim

Good morning,
We are utilizing a 3rd party software to send outbound contracts generated by said program. It is web-based and utilizes its own Mailer and not our pop3/smtp servers to send this email. While I GMAIL passes all SPF checks, if I send to a Microsoft Server it goes IMMEDIATELY into the junk box. How can I prevent this from happening? A lot of our customers and vendors utilize Outlook/Microsoft Exchange Services. They DO NOT have DMARC or DKIM setup on their domain. There's no SPF pass, no fail, just a NONE status... I have the spf records in our DNS settings with the IP's that it is sent from, along with their provided _spf.a####.com -  so any sort of Microsoft Server immediately still flags the email for spoof. The only way I've gotten them to pass is by having to accept it as a spoof through the Security and Compliance center, but I don't want to do this for every employee I have.....

***Microsoft Header Info***

3rd Party Sender - a####.com
Exchange Cloud Emails - kl@######inc.com / ######inc.com
Outside Exchange Email/Outside Company User - e.l#####8@outlook.com

```
######inc.com 60 IN TXT "v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com include:zcsend.net include:_spf.a####.com ip4:###.###.###.0/25 ip4:###.68.###.0/26 ip4:###.###.253.0/26 ip4:###.###.32.0/26 ip4:###.###.238.224/27 ~all"
```

Exchange Headers

```
X-EOPTenantAttributedMessage: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa:0
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageDirectionality: Incoming
X-Forefront-Antispam-Report:
 CIP:70.36.32.23;CTRY:US;LANG:en;SCL:0;SRV:;IPV:NLI;SFV:NSPM;H:d##23.a####.com;PTR:d##23.a####.com;CAT:NONE;SFTY:;SFS:;DIR:INB;SFP:;
X-MS-PublicTrafficType: Email
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource:
 ######.eop-EUR01.prod.protection.outlook.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
X-MS-UserLastLogonTime: 5/13/2020 4:42:31 PM
X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id: 6fee5a11-6f92-4460-2e49-08d7f75ccfdf
X-MS-TrafficTypeDiagnostic: VE1EUR01HT206:
X-MS-Exchange-EOPDirect: true
X-Sender-IP: ##.##.##.23
X-SID-PRA: KL@######INC.COM
X-SID-Result: NONE
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-PCL: 2
X-Microsoft-Antispam: BCL:0;
X-OriginatorOrg: outlook.com
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalArrivalTime: 13 May 2020 16:43:49.1037
 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Network-Message-Id: 6fee5a11-6f92-4460-2e49-08d7f75ccfdf
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Id: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader: Internet
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-RMS-PersistedConsumerOrg:
 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: VE1EUR01HT206
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-EndToEndLatency: 00:00:01.4677680
X-MS-Exchange-Processed-By-BccFoldering: 15.20.3000.016
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: 6
X-Message-Info:
    qoGN4b5S4yqbilezPnhatOC9U6skltNx3TD3J195AJDRLWaN47sSkcFVPDqFmJXjM32PXpyL2Vn3pzaxzNrhkoqbNPBzO4CtkI8NHfb4v07rh/mqh2YuVQ/tYy1A/VRD6qprQ1WDe0eGebAYMtjzsCacMYu6AgWynwzxH0LujGARbFE+Q8AgIzFNVu+NEbsQI/hWWJ9RRmVBPPOdZiSb3A==
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0xO0Q9MjtHRD0xO1NDTD02
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
    abwl:0;wl:0;pcwl:0;kl:0;iwl:0;dwl:0;dkl:0;rwl:0;ucf:0;jmr:0;ex:0;psp:0;auth:0;dest:J;OFR:SpamFilterAuthJ;ENG:(5062000282)(90000001)(90005001)(90010001)(90020001)(9000001)(9010001)(5061607266)(5061608174)(4900115)(58390011)(8390131)(8376100)(8395060)(98390011)(4920090)(6516100)(6394001)(4950130)(4990090)(9140004);RF:JunkEmail;
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Message-Info:
```

Gmail Headers

```
Delivered-To: e.l#####8@gmail.com
Received: by 2002:ad4:418d:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id e13csp360462qvp;
        Wed, 13 May 2020 06:51:07 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: ABdhPJzK970WvVWszl6FMsAOgqxy6CL699y3tXG6OieV/bjVidHGdu9VYzmPeLhXXbW9QQ4O19np
X-Received: by 2002:a50:c014:: with SMTP id r20mr10205271edb.110.1589377867251;
        Wed, 13 May 2020 06:51:07 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1589377867; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=uEeSL4BDn8F7X6+lOlkocObEwvIz++M+/UM10QV0GABVsRZgeJH2yRD/9I6FeDwooO
         TwklHuISaoeBLg/WYaK+ZLGGllhsjC6vVv4D9UZCvELZkYoLET4QU8ZHlDqNKtRvolj5
         4cQrQ3nWbjuesUkRYc2c399Q4OevmBLDJaIslb5/tWNGxYH+QEjfAvfsG+wzQPISswLS
         JFhhjavyuK7o743ObUH3e5wdMlxemsXzoFbLqwC3nW2EKcD2w2sjGGhAt/Oc2UgXY8mA
         dlR2fOS9qe+ICgQl2TPKYkZjMXClAGv95JSrQvl6QatDcdMaZe+fs6/i3gyTaFA3wV/U
         rVyA==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=date:subject:mime-version:message-id:errors-to:sender:reply-to:from
         :to;
        bh=caLvrRx6h8XU/K+DVGOOkDOBXH23fTHYz0z0T57a5+M=;
        b=G/aYv5SXeNhk8bnrBHgFVU9gn2NF6MPnRlU9kX/8h9cX3/03I89HOWlY3kUK1zN2EL
         bILeu/1M9fGiJlNk+9NlILjgVCzbl+HQXIyTP4fwLt9yuWm513Lxhg2yBr+gAFg9RiZz
         TuHYZWyT2eNnzKTxy1o/IHUcB7jwLdPi3tt4vr407MMlg/DmEiAYV7/HfMz4TrUy9yQU
         yhpGZv1WbcRTN/aSiakzJAdu1LvKn4BdFxRwJr0UDiKlO4xXLJyx8pdkj08qXrhPSmJh
         CraHqPOMz9Ey8w2KrEHZ0+M0TbJof1QWao6ZWyqhcfIvcWuVcMdNfud5wIvt2kpPNN29
         q++Q==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of wwwrun@d##23.a#####.com designates ##.##.32.23 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=wwwrun@d##23.a####.com
Return-Path: <wwwrun@d##23.a####.com>
Received: from d##23.a####.com (d##23.a####.com. [##.##.32.23])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id m17si10314011eds.398.2020.05.13.06.51.06
        for <e.l#####8@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Wed, 13 May 2020 06:51:07 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of wwwrun@d##23.a####.com designates ##.##.32.23 as permitted sender) client-ip=##.##.32.23;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of wwwrun@d##23.a####.com designates ##.##.32.23 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=wwwrun@d##23.a####.com
Received: by d##23.a####.com (Postfix, from userid 1003)
    id 64E28660B74C0; Wed, 13 May 2020 09:51:05 -0400 (EDT)
To: e.l#####8@gmail.com
From: kl@######inc.com
Reply-To: kl@######inc.com
Sender: kl@######inc.com
X-Sender: kl@######inc.com
Errors-To: kl@######inc.com
Message-ID: <331199.1589377866@d##23.a####.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Subject: <BOGUS SUBJECT>
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="-"
Date: Wed, 13 May 2020 09:51:05 -0400 (EDT)
```

Comment: There's not enough diagnostic info on the MS side to tell what's going on – their headers are much less informative than Google's. Perhaps ask MS support? One minor tip: put your literal IP mechanisms (`ip4:...`) first; it's faster for receivers to check them because they don't require DNS lookups.

Answer (score 1):

It is by Microsoft design, not to reject but mark as spam

[How Microsoft 365 handles inbound email that fails DMARC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/use-dmarc-to-validate-email?view=o365-worldwide)

If the DMARC policy of the sending server is **p=reject**, EOP marks the message as spoof instead of rejecting it. In other words, for inbound email, Microsoft 365 treats p=reject and p=quarantine the same way. Admins can define the action to take on messages classified as spoof within the anti-phishing policy.

Microsoft 365 is configured like this because some legitimate email may fail DMARC. For example, a message might fail DMARC if it is sent to a mailing list that then relays the message to all list participants. If Microsoft 365 rejected these messages, people could lose legitimate email and have no way to retrieve it. Instead, these messages will still fail DMARC but they will be marked as spam and not rejected.